# How do I replace an HTML element on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am developing this code for a storytelling type game and I need to change the dropbox options after the user or player is done selecting their option. I am trying to make the options in the dropbox relevant to what is happening in the game at the given moment. I was told to do research on a possible change of element(with different options in the dropbox) every time the user has chosen their option.

I have tried some jquery, but only moved the dropbox on click. I could not find any type of operator that could help me with changing it. The append bit in my code is submitting the input and getting an outcome

```html
<div id="actions">
    <select id="chosen_action">
        <option value="You have entered the dungeon...">Yes</option>
        <option value="You turned and left THE END">No</option>
        <option value="You attempted to communicate with the enemy...">Talk</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="append_to_history()">Go!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So when someone chooses You have entered the dungeon, it will auto load a new set of drop down????

Comment: Does this have a c#/java backend or is it pure html/jquery?

Comment: Could you share the JavaScript that you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really easily with `.innerHTML`:

```
$("#chosen_action").innerHTML = `
    <option>You turn away from the castle</option>
    <option>You take a closer look at the old drawbridge</option>
    <option>You decide to consult your map</option>
`;
```

`.innerHTML` simply changes the HTML content of a given element. The backtick operators (`) form a template string, which is capable of spanning multiple lines, making it easier to lay out your new options. You could use a regular string here instead if you'd like (and of course can generate this value with a loop, array, etc).

Comment: @JonP I've updated it to reflect that, thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Well let me explain it a little better so this game is basically a storytelling game where the format is kind of like a terminal you put in input through the dropbox and then you get an output and the story progresses. I need the dropbox options to change once the player has chosen the option. An example would be that there are different options before entering the dungeon and while fighting an enemy so in the beginning there would be one where it asks whether or not you want to enter then I want to change the options for when you are entering a battle with an enemy.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const choice = document.getElementById('chosen_action');
const opt1 = document.getElementById('option1');
const opt2 = document.getElementById('option2');
const opt3 = document.getElementById('option3');
const go = document.getElementById('goButton');

go.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
  if(choice.value !== ""){
    if(choice.value === opt1.value){
      opt1.value = ... //change the value of this element
      opt2.value = ...
      opt3.value = ...
      //if need to change value of text shown to user for selection you can:
      opt1.textContent = ...//change the text of this element
      opt2.textContent = ...
      opt3.textContent = ...
    } else if(choice.value === opt2.value){
      ...
      ...
      ...
    } else{
      ...
      ...
      ...
    }
  } else {
    alert("You must make a choice to continue!")
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="actions">
  <select id="chosen_action">
    <option id="option1" value="You have entered the dungeon...">Yes</option>
    <option id="option2" value="You turned and left THE END">No</option>
    <option id="option3" value="You attempted to communicate with the enemy...">Talk</option>
  </select>
  <button id="goButton" onclick="append_to_history()">Go!</button>
</div>
```

I can't comment to gather more information, so, without knowing more about what you are asking, or where your game is going, or what "append_to_history()" does, or how many possible combinations there are, etc., this is one way of doing what you need to do.

In the end, I would guess you will have to make a giant object, or a great deal of smaller objects, and come up with a naming system that you can programmatically grab the proper values from when it comes time. Probably a tracker to count the number of choices (each button click) and then name your objects accordingly, so that you can use the tracker value and the option number to call the correct value. You will have to figure out, at some point, every single possible value and then programmatically call them for each new value depending on the value chosen at time of click.

Would be interested to know if anyone else has any different perspective on this, though!

Comment: Append history gives back output once you selected something in the dropbox

Comment: @ReficulFotsen26 both answers here are correct, but would be used for different circumstances. I did not recommend `.innerHTML` because, if this is a complex storyline, with more than, say, 3-4 steps (just after 3 steps, you would have written 39 different possible answers, and after 4 steps, you would have written 120), you would have to completely re-write a new html div for each answer, instead of just replacing the values for each answer.